# How Retain authorization header when a redirect happens to a different hostname?

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from a secure end point, the endpoint as I understand now redirect to a different host name, therefore I lose my auth variable

with the following **curl** command **everything works**:

```
curl -u user:pass --location --location-trusted --cookie-jar test "url"
```

But when I try getting the data with python requests library I can not succeed

```
MY_URI ="url"
USERNAME = "user"
PASSWORD = "pass"
r=requests.get(url=MY_URI, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))#,allow_redirects=False)
```

- allow_redirects=False response is 302
- without  allow_redirects=False response is 401

from my search online I didnt find any snippet that worked ( i tried at least 10 different ones)

- I manage to get the data as well with postman using BasicAuth with my username and password and **only if the setting Follow Authorization header is on**

My question, how can I convert the curl\postman to python ?

would appreciate any help

thx in advance

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?